# Keyboard stops working in Safari iOS 6 when clearing contenteditable div

Tags: ios, ios6, dom-events, contenteditable

I have a `div` that is `contenteditable` which holds a placeholder until you click it.
If I clear the contents of the `div` on `focus` in Safari in iOS 6.1 I am unable to use the keyboard.
It works fine in Firefox, Chrome and Safari on iOS 7.

If doesn't work either if you refocus the `div` (and ensure next time the content doesn't change).

Is there a fix for this as I'm making a web app that needs to support iOS 6?

Here's some test code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div contenteditable="true">click here</div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('focus', function(event) {
                event.target.textContent = '';
            });
         </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

which can be tested here: http://jsbin.com/efofUNi/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try delaying blanking out the textContent for a few milliseconds. For example:

```
document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('focus', function(event) {
    setTimeout(function() { 
       event.target.textContent = '';
    }, 5);
});
```

That will work around this issue in Safari on iOS 6.1.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I already tried this, but trying it again it works. Thanks!